# How to show only first 15 characters of text value

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

text from array [`.ts` file] is displayed on `home.html`

I want to show only first `15 characters` and then 3 dots `...`

This is the code I am trying to use but it is not working

`home.html`

```
<ion-content>
  <!--<div class="info col-11"  [innerHtml]="list.dr_describe | safe: 'html'">{{list.q_describe}}</div>-->

  <div class="info col-11" *ngFor="let list of this.dailyreports">
    {{list.name}}
    <br/>
    <span [innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'">{{list.desc.substring(1,15)}}</span>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Here is the screenshot of my html page:

[image]

Comment: Could you please say what is the purpose of `[innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'"`? Also first 15 characters would be `substring(0,15)`. Index starts at 0.

Comment: This question appears additionally to be lacking a [mcve], since "not working" is not a useful fault report. Please edit it to describe a specific problem.

Comment: user2828442: some of your questions have been edited recently, but your new questions are replicating the same errors. Your posts have a needy, begging quality, and suggests you think that displays of helplessness will cause people to pity your situation and/or feel coerced into the social obligation of assisting the less fortunate. This is not appropriate behaviour for a volunteer platform. The personal pronoun ("I") is also always an upper case, as you well know. Please have mercy on volunteer editors, who do not wish to clear up after you.

Comment: @MichaelD `[innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'"` shows the data with html properties,`{{list.desc.substring(0,15)}}</span>` is not working

Comment: @halfer this is how i speak english, i dont beg, please control

Comment: Meaning is what people read, not what the writer meant. There are plenty of discussions on Meta that indicate that technical writing is preferred here, [such as this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260776/should-i-remove-fluff-when-editing-questions). I currently take the view that your historical unwillingness to interact means you are not willing to be part of a collaborative and helpful community, and I would urge you to change course if you can. It is not a substantial or unreasonable request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
  {{ (list.desc.length>15)? (list.desc  | slice:0:15)+'...':(list.desc ) }}
```

or use custom Pipe is better

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'shorten'
})
export class ShortenPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val:string , length?: any):string[] {
    return (val.length>length)? val.slice(0, 15)+'...':val
  }
}
```

in HTML

```
{{list.desc | shorten:15 }}
```

Comment: none of the 2 is working :(

Comment: Can you come online for 2 minutes so i can show you, i created shorten pipe, added in `viewreport.module.ts` [import, added in declaration], it did not work, then tried your other solution, still did not work, this is how code looks at the moment `<span [innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'">{{ (list.desc.length>15)? (list.desc  | slice:0:15)+'...':(list.desc ) }}</span>`

Comment: On further investigation please note - the data i am receiving is in html format like bold,color property and using `[innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'"` this renders it as html text on the page, now if i remove this code, all works but i get html code... i need it with html property

Comment: @user2828442 can you demonstrate your problem in stackblitz

Comment: it will be a lot of work as it using tiny mce editor, with just text it is working

Comment: This needs to be changed in answer: ```val.slice(0, 15)```   -->  ```val.slice(0, length)```

Answer (score 3):

Create custom pipe  like this

```
@Pipe({
  name: 'customslice'
})
export class CustomSlice implements PipeTransform {
  transform(val:string , length:number):string {
    return val.length > length ? `${val.substring(0, length)} ...` : val
  }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
{{mystr | customslice : 15 }}
```

Comment: your solution works in case "mystr" is greater than 15 but if  "mystr" is less than 15 ? the result will be with 3 dots

Comment: updated the solution. if string length is less than 15 return the entire string

Comment: yes good :), just can you change 15 as a variable for CustomSlice pipe, to be more generic

Comment: updated the answer as per your comment

Comment: where do i need to import the pipe in `home.module.ts` or `home.ts` ?

Comment: You can add it into shared modules declaration array and exports array and import shared module in the module where your component is part of

Comment: added in `viewreport.module.ts` - `import` - `import { ShortenPipe } from './../pipes/shorten/shorten.pipe';`  and added in declaraction `ShortenPipe` , in html - `<span [innerHtml]="list.desc | safe: 'html'">{{list.desc | shorten:15}}</span>` , no error and not working

Comment: Is your component part of ViewReport module?